# Ubuntu Firefox homepage temporarily showing Arabic

Tags: firefox

I've noticed this evening that the default Ubuntu Firefox homepage on Ubuntu 12.04 momentarily displayed Arabic in the titlebar and for the links. This first happened 15 mins ago then I rebooted and tried again - still Arabic.

Just now I've tried one more time and it's now gone back to English.

No other application on my system (e.g. Chrome or the console) is displaying any Arabic and I've double checked my localisation settings and it's still English UK.

Also when I visited any other page on Firefox (e.g the normal Google search page, http://www.google.co.uk) the normal English page showed, not an Arabic version.

Any ideas on this one? Guessing it might have been a problem server side as it was the server-generated content showing Arabic - nothing client-side - as it seems to have sorted itself out just now... but just thought I'd check.

Have deleted all my cookies just in case it was an attempted XSS attack or something like that - but I haven't been doing anything silly so I'd suspect not.

It's 12.04, more or less up-to-date (just updated 5 packages now from last week, so now completely up-to-date), and localisation is English UK.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Please post this as a bug report in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox

Comment: This happened to me today after reinstalling due to router issues and it sorted itself out but left me feeling uneasy. Did you ever find out what it was? Also, have you had any security issues since it's been 3 months?