# Firefox default language keeps changing automatically to arabic

Tags: firefox, language-support, malware

I am getting an ongoing issue with Firefox 36.0 under Ubuntu 15.04.

Whenever I open Firefox it automatically sets the default language to Arabic, even though having never configured it to use Arabic:

[image]

When I run `locale` in terminal I get:

```
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I tried already removing completely Firefox following [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed) and then re-installed again, it installed successfully using default language EN, but after some days when I open Firefox it is automatically set to default language Arabic again.

Just for safety I removed Firefox and am using only Chrome at the moment, I don't know if this is a virus or a bug related to any specific versions if there's anyone who might know I appreciate.

Comment: Can you run the `locale` command in a terminal window, and let us know what it outputs by editing your question.

Comment: Do you use Arabic at all elsewhere on the desktop? If you suspect a security breach on your machine, you might be best off wiping your hard drive and reinstalling your whole system, just to be sure.

Comment: 15.04 is not out yet, this question is off-topic here. Report a bug instead --> http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: no I don't use it at all, and never configured it, it just happens automatically when I open Firefox. I just seen this in Firefox alone not in any other apps.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/520928/ubuntu-firefox-homepage-temporarily-showing-arabic

Comment: It's not the Firefox language; it's the web page content language.

Comment: @AliNa: Which is controlled by the browser language, isn't it?

Comment: No, webpage language preference is separate from UI locale or encoding in Firefox.

Comment: I researched a bit and it seems to be related to adware, I was able to fix it resetting Firefox, and lately after updating both FF and Ubuntu 15.04 I stopped getting it, so I'll close this question for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped getting it after updating both FF and Ubuntu, and after refreshing firefox:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Edit** -> **Preferences** -> **Contents** *tab* and click the **Choose...** *button* to see the preferred languages. You can *remove* Arabic or *Move Down* to make it less preferred.

[image: Content Languages]

As you can see on the upper part of the window, this setting is for *displaying web pages* offered in more than one language. So it have nothing to do with browser language nor with any locales.

Comment: I understand that but what happened in my case is that I never configured or added Arabic, neither use it in any ways, I always use english as default language for Firefox but suddenly Firefox changed the default start page to Arabic with no human intervention, as from my posted image, so I suspect something related to malware in this case.

Comment: @guilhebl: Is Arabic included in your language preference list in Firefox? In that case, and while I have no idea why it happened, you can simply remove it.

Comment: I too am having this problem.  My Ubuntu start page has changed itself first to Spanish, and then later to Turkish.  The menu described here lists only en-us and en in my preferences.

Comment: I also once got the message changed to Turkish, I researched a bit and it seems to be related to adware, I was able to fix it resetting Firefox, and lately after updating both FF and Ubuntu 15.04 I stopped getting it, so I'll close this question for now.